# EmberJS content binding not working

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following code:

JS:

```
MapSearch.FiltersList = Ember.Object.extend({
        content: [
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "Gender", actualValue: "gender"}),
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "Marital Status", actualValue: "msc105"}),
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "Council Tax Band", actualValue: "thc140"}),
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "Length Of Residency", actualValue: "mhc117"}),
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "Household Composition", actualValue: "mhc110"}),
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "Income Value Banded - Profiling", actualValue: "mgc131"}),
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "Property Value Banded - Profiling", actualValue: "mgc111"}),
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "Property Value Banded - 10% UK", actualValue: "mgc112"}),
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "Landscape Lifestyle", actualValue: "mgc120"}),
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "UK Lifestyle Group", actualValue: "bgc422"}),
        Ember.Object.create({textValue: "UK Wealth Group", actualValue: "bgc422"})
        ]

});
MapSearch.FilterSelect = Ember.Select.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['name', 'id'],
    contentBinding: 'MapSearch.FiltersList.content'
});
```

Handlebars:

```
    {{view MapSearch.FilterSelect name="filter_type" id="filter_type" class="filter_type"  optionValuePath="actualValue"   optionLabelPath="textValue"}}
```

However I get a blank select. I know I'm doing something wrong, but cant figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your `FiltersList` an `ArrayController`, and creating the instance, not defining it with `extend`.

```
MapSearch.FiltersList = Em.ArrayController.create({

    content: [
    ....
    ]

})
```

Note that you can make things slightly more efficient by creating your binding like

`contentBinding: Em.Binding.oneWay('MapSearch.FiltersList.content')`

if your select input cannot change the content values.

Comment: Jesus. I tried `ArrayController` but missed the `create`. Thanks so much, saved me such a headache. Will accept when the 10 min is reached :)

Comment: awesome. Never delved that far into the binding class. Cheers